# Configuring Health Cloud Patients List in Lightning

Tags: health-cloud

I am trying to configure a Health Cloud instance to work with the lighting interface. I have followed the guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_lex_setup_checklist.htm) and have successfully created a patient list view. In the lightning interface, when I attempt to click a patient record, I am not navigated to the record however. I have verified that a Flexipage exists for Patient Console and is assigned to my app. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you testing in pre release org on Summer 20 ?